# I Need Find A Mac Address from a client connected to my Teamspeak

Tags: iptables, mysql, mac-address

I have a dedicated server and from it I am running a teamspeak 3 server.
In teamspeak server there is a client who need to be banned. I have banned him from teamspeak but if you change your windows product key you can connect again to the teamspeak server. So i wonder if I can find somewhere his mac address in order to ban him using iptables. My server is running on Debian 7.7 and teamspeak has has a mysql server.

Comment: You can also change you MAC address. Would banning by IP address be better?

Comment: if i just ban his ip he can change it later if he restarts his router

Comment: you can see a list of mac,IP usinf /sbin/arp -an (or arp -an being root). However to see the mac adress the client must be on the same network, which is probably not the case.

Comment: @GiannisKyriazis Good point. Can you just password protect it?

Comment: @Archemar I thought that Teamspeak might plausibly request MAC addresses from clients?

Comment: I don't know about teamspeak requesting mac adress, but you can't get it directly from unix (unless being on same network).

Comment: @sparhawk I thought it too but it is a public teamspeak server with 100 clients everyday I can't just password protect it :/

Comment: @archemar well yeah i don't thing that teamspeak requests mac address so i thought maybe they are kept into the server somewhere, somehow

Comment: @GiannisKyriazis I'm really not sure then. As I say, even if the MAC address is transmitted, then it's facile to spoof. (At least in Linux, not sure about Windows.) I guess the only half-workable solution is ban by IP and hope that he gets bored of restarting his router…

Comment: @sparhawk thats a solution too but till now i'm the bored one banning him from both teamspeak and iptables

Comment: Can you not ban by hostname, and then explicitly add others from his host?